# Largest collection of pairwise relatively prime polynomials with bounded individual degree

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, polynomials, algebraic-curves

Suppose $\mathcal{P}$ is a set of polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_p[x_1, \dots, x_m]$ with the properties that

- any $f\in \mathcal{P}$ has degree at most $d-1$ in each variable $x_i$, and
- any distinct $f,g\in \mathcal{P}$ are relatively prime.

What is the largest possible value of $\mathcal{P}$ ? More generally, I'd be interested in hearing about any lower bounds on $|\mathcal{P}|$.

Comment: We can assume each $f\in\mathcal{P}$ is squarefree, since we can replace a factor $g^k$ with $k>1$ by $g$. Now if $f\in\mathcal{P}$ is reducible, say $f=uv$, then we can replace $f$ with the two polynomials $u,v$. Thus you are asking for the number of irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_p[x_1,\dots,x_m]$ which are of degree at most $d-1$ in each variable.

Comment: As a follow-up on my previous comment: for the number of irreducible polynomials see https://www.jstor.org/stable/27642561?seq=1 and references therein.